# DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

hello~could u help me to solve the questions?

【Anaconda3-4.4.0】

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:123456@localhost:3306/mysql?charset=utf8')
sql = pd.read_sql('all_gzdata', engine, chunksize = 10000)

counts = [ i['fullURLId'].value_counts() for i in sql] 
counts = pd.concat(counts).groupby(level=0).sum() 
counts = counts.reset_index() 
counts.columns = ['index', 'num'] 
counts['type'] = counts['index'].str.extract('(\d{3})') 
counts_ = counts[['type', 'num']].groupby('type').sum()
```

**the above codes are normal，but if I add the sentence below，python warns“'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort'”**

```
counts_.sort('num', ascending = False)
```

Answer (score 3):

...Question solved.

The last code should be **"counts_.sort_values('num',ascending=False)"** instead.